# Initializing LeafletProvider

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I am rendering my map as following:

```
public render() {
        const polygon = this.props.region && <XPolygon polygon={this.props.region.polygon}/>;
        return (
            <Map center={[32.01739159980399, 34.84863281250001]} zoom={12} ref={this.mapRef}
                 onClick={this.onClick}
                 containerElement={<div style={{height: `100vh`}}/>}
                 mapElement={<div style={{height: `100vh`}}/>}
                 loadingElement={<div style={{height: `100vh`}}/>}>
                <TileLayer url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"/>
                <LocateControl/>
                {polygon}
            </Map>
        )
}
```

I want to use `<LeafletProvider value={...}>` to pass context down the DOM.
What should I put into provider's value when I am initializing map the way above?